# Powershell: Get default system encoding

Tags: powershell, file-encodings

The powershell cmdlet `out-file` has the switch `-encoding` witch you can set to `default`. This default value will use the encoding of the system's current ANSI code page.
My question is: How can I get the name of this default encoding that `out-file` will use with powershell?

Comment: I am not using default anymore. My experience is that "current ANSI code page" translates to "something that other programs are not really fond of except notepad", which I believe is a multibyte Unicode .

Comment: @J.N. I don't want to use default, but I have to. Normally I would use UTF8 or UTF16, but in this case I have some problems with legacy code.

Comment: @Oscaso : I wish you a better luck next time! There should be best practices forbidding the writing of legacy code from the start. I wonder why nobody did it yet :).

Comment: @J.N. Thanks! Let's hope so, by goodness!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Take a look at `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default`, I believe it is used as "default".

E.g. in my case:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.EncodingName
```

gets

```
Cyrillic (Windows)
```

Comment: That looks exactly like what i want. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use [System.Text.Encoding]::Default to get everthing.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem with Windows Server 2012 and `zabbix.exe->cmd.exe->Powershell.exe` by using the following:

```
-old string:UserParameter=get.gost-pcidss.csv, powershell.exe -encodedCommand Yw....
-new string:UserParameter=get.gost-pcidss.csv,@chcp 65001>nul && powershell.exe -encodedCommand Yw....
```

In `encodedCommand`, I use `chcp 65001;` at the first line.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you please clarify your answer?