# Encoding CSV content to UTF-8

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8

So I have this powershell script Which import a csv file, replacing null into '0' and export this csv.

The issue is that the content and header of this csv is in hebrew

I tried almost everything
Used -Encoding for all types of encoding but nothing

Any Suggestions?

```
$propertyTranslation = @(
    @{ Name = 'Customer__c';   Expression = { $_.'לקוח' } }
    @{ Name = 'Name__c';       Expression = { $_.'שם'  } }
    @{ Name = 'CheckCount__c'; Expression = { $_.'כמות'  } }
    @{ Name = 'Deal';          Expression = { $_.'עסקהוזה'  } }
    @{ Name = 'Amount__c';     Expression = { $_.'סכום'  } }
    @{ Name = 'Discount__c';   Expression = { $_.'ניסיון'  } }
    # And so on
)

$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\alon\Documents\again.csv -Header "Customer__c","Name__c","Deal","Amount__c","CheckCount__c","Discount__c" 

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Customer__c -eq "")   { $_.Customer__c = "0" }
    if($_.Name__c -eq "")       { $_.Name__c = "0" }
    if($_.Deal -eq "")          { $_.Deal = "0" }
    if($_.Amount__c -eq "")     { $_.Amount__c = "0" }
    if($_.Discount__c -eq "")   { $_.Discount__c = "0" }
    if($_.CheckCount__c -eq "") { $_.CheckCount__c = "0" }
} 

Select-Object -Property $propertyTranslation 

$csv | Export-Csv C:\Users\alon\Documents\CheckDealBeforeUpsert.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Your `$propertyTranslation` type is `system.array`; consider a [Hash Table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) instead, something like `$propertyTranslation = @{
'Customer__c' = 'לקוח';
'Name__c' = 'שם' ;
'CheckCount__c' = 'כמות' ;
'Deal' = 'עסקהוזה' ;
'Amount__c' = 'סכום' ;
'Discount__c' = 'ניסיון'
}`. However, I'd say that your script could work if you do omit `$propertyTranslation` at all.

Comment: Ok thanks for your feedvak

Comment: You can see om my code (Last row take a bit right) That i tries to use -Encoding.

Comment: Sorry.  You are right. Have you tried _reading_ the file with the `-Encoding` as well. The problem starts there.

Comment: Hi matt, Do you mean before importing? (I'm a bit new on powershell scripting) - Thanks in advance!

Comment: The source file is UTF-8 as well correct? If that is the case you need your Import-CSV line to be using `-Encoding` as well. `$csv = Import-Csv C:\Users\alon\Documents\again.csv -Header "..." -Encoding UTF8`

Comment: The source file is ANSI

Comment: `$csv | Select-Object $propertyTranslation  | Export-Csv C:\Users\alon\Documents\CheckDealBeforeUpsert.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8` You created calculated properties in order to change some values? you are not using them. I don't know if it will do what you expect but if you have columns with hebrew characters you need to be exporting that. I might be lost on how you are manipulating your input.

Comment: Matt thanks, you helped me understand that the issue is the csv encoded as ANSI - when i manually change the encoding to UTF8 and did as you advised - It works. The issue that the files are always will be ANSI (Batch files)

Comment: What is your default encoding on your system? Perhaps your PowerShell is not opening that file with ANSI to begin with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326304/powershell-get-default-system-encoding. I am not great with encoding issues as I do not deal with them enough.

Comment: Ok matt, I will look for a way to change the system default encoding. Thanks you so much for you assist!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your hashtable is backwards. What you posted in your question would translate hebrew to english headers. If you want it the other way 'round you need to put the hebrew string as the name and the english property as the expression of the hashtables (e.g. `@{n='לקוח';e={$_.Customer__c}}`). Or you could just import the CSV using the hebrew headers.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, the issue is with the content, not the header

Comment: Well, what exactly *is* the issue in the first place? You said it's an encoding issue, but how exactly does the issue manifest itself? Can you provide sample input and output (preferably along with a hexdump of the first couple bytes of input and output)? You said the source file has ANSI encoding, but which codepage exactly? ANSI in PowerShell terms usually means windows-1252 whereas the codepage for hebrew is windows-1255. Not sure if that depends on the Windows language version.

Comment: The issue is that I'm using a script to add '0' to empty cells because a groovy scrip collapse once it hits empty cells. The issue is that this script above return "???????" Where the content is Hebrew

Comment: Did you try `Import-Csv -Encoding OEM`? If that doesn't work you may need to convert the input file to UTF-8 first, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32121665/1630171) (try with `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1255)` for the reader and `[Text.Encoding]::UTF8` for the writer).

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thanks for your assistance! not sure I understood the code (a bit newbie on powershell) but I will try

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, It works!

Answer (score 2):

The term "ANSI" as it is used in Windows is basically an umbrella term for a number of encodings (or code pages). Usually it refers to the [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding. Your input file, however, appears to be encoded using the [windows-1255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) code page.

I'm not sure if in PowerShell `-Encoding ASCII` always means windows-1252 encoding, or if that is adjusted for localized Windows versions. If it's not adjusted you probably need to convert your input file to an encoding `Import-Csv` can handle before you can import and modify the data:

```
$inFile  = 'C:\path\to\input.csv'
$outFile = 'C:\path\to\input_utf8.csv'

$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader ($inFile, [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1255))
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ($outFile, $false, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)

while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
  $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine())
}

$reader.Close(); $reader.Dispose()
$writer.Close(); $writer.Dispose()
```